# What does The Father do?

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, god-the-father

It seems like such a basic question: what does the Father do? It is said that the Holy Spirit is the life-giver and speaks through the prophets and everything is made through the Son, Jesus, and Jesus is also the way by which we are saved and will judge the world. According to Trinitarians, what is the role of the Father?

Comment: Although it is worded differently, there is a related question : [What was God's goal in Creating Life ?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75417/what-was-gods-goal-in-creating-life).

Comment: The Father is who God is as uncaused source..  The Son is what God thinks and says.  The Holy Spirit is God's operative power.  Therefore Jesus only does and says, by the power of the Holy Spirit, what God the Father wills.

Answer (score 1):

The Father is the source of everything.   (1 Co 8:6a).

> [1 Corinthians 8:6 English Standard Version (ESV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%208%3A6&version=ESV)
>   6 yet for us there is **one God, the Father, from whom are all things** and for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist

Contra your question,  He is also the one who spoke through the prophets as per Hebrews 1:1-2.

He is also the maker of all things, and that through His Son at Hebrews 1:2.

> Hebrews 1:1-2 **God**, having of old time **spoken unto the fathers in the prophets** by divers portions and in divers manners, **hath at the end of these days spoken unto us in his Son**, whom he appointed heir of all things, through whom also he made the worlds. (ASV)

Comment: When I said that The Holy Spirit speaks through the prophets I was referring to the Nicene Creed. After all, Hebrews doesn't specify which person of the Trinity speaks through the prophets. To address your first point, that The Father is the origin of all things, as far as I can see that's the only thing that different Christian texts attribute to the Father. Other than being the origin of everything, including the other two persons of the Trinity, does the Father have any specific role? Or has all authority been delegated to Christ for the rest of time?

Comment: @MATTHEW  Hebrews 1:1-2 is very specific.   In the past of the writing of the passage God who has a Son spoke by means of the prophets.   Then he spoke by means of his Son.  God in this context  can only be the Father even to a Trinitarian.    For the rest of time?   Read the context!   It's at the end of the days.    As for authority read 1 Co 15:27.

Answer (score -1):

You should read about the [economic trinity](https://carm.org/dictionary-economic-trinity). Basically, the Father plans, elects, foreknows, ordains, and sends.